# How do you drill-through from a chart to different reports depending on the chart value?

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi

I have a pie chart in Cognos 11, and depending on the slice I'd like to drill-through to different reports.  My particular pie has 4 slices, and 4 different reports I'd like to drill-through to depending on the value.

I've seen tutorials on how to drill through conditionally via a Crosstab, but not for a chart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able drill through to four different reports. That would require the ability to define four different drill-through definitions when each chart only contains one. However, I do believe there's a workaround.

The workaround would be to use a single drill-through target report and have it conditionally render data elements based on the passed in parameters.

Consider a simple pie chart which shows Sales as its measure and Department as its series (slices). Let's assume that there are four departments: Food, Housewares, Clothes, Hardware.

The chart when rendered will have four slices, one for each of the four departments. You define the drill-through to pass in the Department data item value to the target report.

On the target report side, you take the value passed in and selectively render the contents based on the value. This can be done several ways:

- Create a page for each format and only render one at a time based on passed in Department value
- Create four different data containers on a single page and only render one at a time
- Create a conditional block and have each report format in one of the block options

Personally I like doing this with multiple pages. It's cleaner and makes your intent to others clearer, especially if you name the pages descriptively.

A possible complication is filters. It would be a challenge is the filters used in each "format" was vastly different. It could still be worked around would be more challenging.

By the way, what I described above relates to Cognos Report Studio 10.x. I'm not sure if any or all of this translates to Cognos 11 as I don't have access to that version. It's my understanding that underneath the new simplified UI, the new Cognos is pretty much the same, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: Your workaround is very similar to my other post (which you also added an answer to), and if I knew how then I would agree that'd be the best solution.

To tailor your example to my exact situation, let's say the pie charts are inside of a repeater table, so you'll get a different pie for Food, Housewares, Clothes, and Hardware.  Each pie is then broken down by sales by product.  I would then like to pass the department name and the product.  So if the "Food" department had a slice with 10 apples, then I'd like to pass that to a report with product detail that shows the 10 apples.

Comment: In my situation I would need to pass "Apples", and "Food". Let's say the target report contains a different list for food, housewares, clothes, and hardware.  The only way I know (I've used Cognos for 2 months and have no prior experience w/ development) is to create a variable, which will then render the correct list.  It would be straightforward to pass "Food" and render the food list.  But... how do I pass "apple" at the same time so it then filters that Food list by apples?

Comment: If you are using a repeater table, then the value you are breaking out by (in this case Department) should be in the chart's source query as you have to setup the master-detail relationship on a common value. You should be able to pass this data item value in via a drill-through by specific the 'Method' as 'Pass data item value' and the 'Value' as the department data item. I mocked up a repeater-based chart report and was able to do this.

Comment: I created a concept report, and the drill-through on multiple data items function as expected.  I'm afraid there may be a different underlying issue with my initial report that is causing it to not work.  Thanks for the feedback!